# Export slickgrid to pdf and retain the formatting that is done in the UI to show the data

Tags: javascript, pdf, export, slickgrid

Currently the export functionality for the pdf is

`<a href="#" onclick="$('.slickGrid').tableExport({type:'pdf',pdfFontSize:'20',escape:'false',tableName:'Asset Report',pdfLeftMargin:20,htmlContent:'true'});"> <img src="icons/pdf.png" style="width:24px"> PDF</a>`

This is exporting the grid but the formatting is all gone and the data is getting truncated as the grid is expanding horizontally. 
Need a way to fix this, any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are exporting the grid using tableExport.jquery.plugin, which does not have proper customization support. For example, as far as I can see [here](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin/blob/master/jspdf/jspdf.js#L116), font defaults to Helvetica and can't be changed.

I think you should try implementing export on server side using some library like [wkhtmltopdf](http://wkhtmltopdf.org/), which converts html to pdf and also supports css and js (it runs browser engine under the hood).

Comment: I'm using the jQuery 1.11, this seems as a command line tool in C, I am looking for something as .js plugin to be  add to handle this export functionality, maintaining/retaining the CSS styling of the grid.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to do it properly on client side because you have to render html for the canvas yourself (that's what libraries like `tableExport` probably do) and it's far not an easy task. Anyway, you can also try [jsPdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF).